# Why isn't all the data being stored?

Tags: python

I have a dictionary carrying key:value however it only saves the last iteration and discards the previous entries where is it being reset ?? This is the output from the ctr of iterations and the length of the dictionary

```
Return the complete Term and DocID Ref.
LENGTH:6960
CTR:88699
```

My code:

```
class IndexData:

    def getTermDocIDCollection(self):
        ...............
            for term in terms:
    #TermDocIDCollection[term] = sourceFile['newid']
                TermDocIDCollection[term] = []
                 TermDocIDCollection[term].append(sourceFile['newid'])
        return TermDocIDCollection
```

Comment: Do you mean that the file may contain each key more than once and the dictionary is keeping only the last entry for each one? If that's what you mean, that's how it works. `dict.update` is going to add new keys or replace the existing ones.

Comment: Oh thats exactly whats happening but as you see i commented the section of the list and it was doing the same though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The piece of code you've commented out does the following:

1. Sets a value to the key (removing whatever was there before, if it existed)
2. Sets a new value to the key (an empty list)
3. Appends the value set in step 1 to the new empty list

Sadly, it would do the same each iteration, so you'd end up with `[last value]` assigned to the key. The new code (with `update`) does something similar. In the old days you'd do this:

```
if term in TermDocIDCollection:
    TermDocIDCollection[term].append(sourceFile['newid'])
else:
    TermDocIDCollection[term] = [sourceFile['newid']]
```

or a variation of the theme using `try`-`except`. After `collections` was added you can do this instead:

```
from collections import defaultdict

# ... code...

TermDocIDCollection = defaultdict(list)
```

and you'd update it like this:

```
TermDocIDCollection[term].append(sourceFile['newid'])
```

no need to check if `term` exists in the dictionary. If it doesn't, the `defaultdict` type will first call to the constructor you passed (`list`) to create the initial value for the key

Comment: My Goal is to have steps 2 and 3 (step 1 was another attempt of something else) keeping all duplicate terms with there unique values how do i go about doing this ? Thank  you

Comment: Notice that I've posted two solutions to the problem. One is the classical (check if the key exists in the dictionary: if it does, append; if it doesn't create a new list containing just the first value), and one using `defaultdict`

Comment: If your new code is like the one you're showing now, then no, you haven't. You're blindly setting `TermDocIDCollection[term] = []` **every time**. You need to understand that any assignment like that will **replace** the previous content with the new one.

Comment: KSM: NP, it's a classic. You'd find plenty of examples on StackOverflow :-)

Comment: im still confused to why by LENGTH:6960 is not same as my
CTR:88699

Comment: CTR counts the number of entries in the file, while the length of a dictionary is the number of *keys* it contains. That means you've got 6960 unique keys in your file.

Comment: See thats the thing i need all they keys not just unique keys

Comment: Yeah, but a dictionary can ONLY have one entry per key. That's why you're storing the multiple entries for a same key as a list.

Comment: To summarize: a dictionary is simply a key-value structure, optimized to efficiently recover information on a key basis. You can have the same value associated to multiple keys, but each key can appear only once. The value can be anything, though, meaning you can organize the multiple values for a key in the way you prefer (a list, a contatenation of strings, ... depends on your data)